# How to replace space in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, str-replace

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "/goget       　         sdflfasfdsaf";
```

There're some `Half-width space` and `Full-width space` between `/goget` and `sdflfasfdsaf`, so I want to replace all spaces with only one `Half-width space`

My javascript code like this:

```
var newstr = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");
console.log(newstr.replace("/goget","/goget "))
```

but I think it is not good, how can I improve this code?

Comment: What are the actual characters for half-width and full-width spaces?

Comment: "is not good", does it work or not? Why do you want to improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I understand from your code is that you can call `str.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` directly instead of again calling `replace()`.

```js
var str = "/goget       　         sdflfasfdsaf";
var newstr = str.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
console.log(newstr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and `join()` operations:

```js
var str = "/goget       　         sdflfasfdsaf";
str = str.split(/\s+/).join(' ');
console.log(str);
```

Or with `replace()` use `str.replace(/\s+/, ' ');`:

```js
var str = "/goget       　         sdflfasfdsaf";
str = str.replace(/\s+/, ' ');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @yupang glad to help

Answer (score 1):

you can call str.replace(/ /g, '')

```js
var str = "/goget       　         sdflfasfdsaf";
var newstr = str.replace(/ /g,'');
console.log(newstr)
```